# How to align the contents of a label nicely in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, label, word-wrap

The below code is the code of a label in my JavaFX application. It has some problems. setWrapText() and setTextAlignment() methods are working, but there are some defects. The main defect is that, there is no space between some words. Since there is no space they are shown as a single word.

How can I solve this issue ?

```
    Label t1;
    t1 = new Label("\t\t Here you add the details of the staff, subject and students. "
            + "Then allocate staff for each subject. They will perform mark "
            + "entry for each and every student, you entered. You just check "
            + "whether they are doing everything as per your advice. "
            + "You can view the marklist of every subject since you "
            + "are the tutor of the class.");
    t1.setWrapText(true);
    t1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
    t1.setPrefWidth(560);
    t1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
    t1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.

[image]

OS X 10.9, Java 8b129, Macbook Air 2012.